# Turning denormalized table into a nested structure

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

pretty junior data analyst here

I'm trying to turn denormalized event data from GA4 into a more BI friendly nested format.
Raw GA4 data schema:
[GA4 schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JfRK.png)

The starting point is data on an event level, but as I'm trying to create a deep dive user dashboard based on user_pseudo_id, I want to create three abstraction layers:

1. A user level containing device information, overall stats, and the sessions as a nested REPEATING RECORD
2. A session level containing containing geographical data, length of session, amount of visited pages, and all the events of the session as a nested REPEATING RECORD
3. An event level containing timestamp, event type and event specific information.

My code so far:

```
...events_joined_with_transactions AS (
    SELECT
        ue.*,
        t.transaction_id,
        t.currency,
        t.shipping,
        t.tax,
        t.revenue,
        t.unique_items,
        t.total_items,
        t.items
    FROM user_events AS ue
    LEFT JOIN transactions AS t
    ON ue.event_name = "purchase"
    AND ue.user_pseudo_id = t.user_pseudo_id
    AND t.timestamp = ue.timestamp
),

sessions AS (
    SELECT
        user_pseudo_id,
        session_id,
        source_medium,
        campaign_name,
        ARRAY_AGG(
            STRUCT(
                date, 
                timestamp,
                event_name,
                event_specific_info
            )
        ) AS events
    FROM events_joined_with_transactions
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
),

users AS (
    SELECT
        user_pseudo_id,
        SUM(IF(event_name != "user_engagement", 1, 0)) AS total_events,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "session_start", 1, 0)) AS sessions,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "page_view", 1, 0)) AS view_page,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "view_item", 1, 0)) AS view_item,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "add_to_cart", 1, 0)) AS add_to_cart,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "remove_from_cart", 1, 0)) AS remove_from_cart,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "add_payment_info", 1, 0)) AS add_payment_info,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "add_shipping_info", 1, 0)) AS add_shipping_info,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "begin_checkout", 1, 0)) AS begin_checkout,
        SUM(IF(event_name = "purchase", 1, 0)) AS transactions,
        SUM(shipping) AS total_shipping,
        SUM(tax) AS total_tax,
        SUM(revenue) AS total_revenue,
        SUM(total_items) AS total_items,
    FROM events_joined_with_transactions
    GROUP BY 1
),

final AS (
    SELECT
        u.user_pseudo_id,
        u.total_events,
        u.sessions,
        u.view_page,
        u.view_item,
        u.add_to_cart,
        u.remove_from_cart,
        u.add_payment_info,
        u.add_shipping_info,
        u.begin_checkout,
        u.transactions,
        u.total_shipping,
        u.total_tax,
        u.total_revenue,
        u.total_items,
        ARRAY_AGG(
            session_id,
            source_medium,
            campaign_name,
            events
        ) AS sessions
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN sessions s
    USING(user_pseudo_id)
)

SELECT *
FROM final
```

However, I get the following error message:

> The argument to ARRAY_AGG must not be an array type but was ARRAY<STRUCT<date DATE, timestamp TIMESTAMP, event_name STRING, event_specific_info ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_val STRING, int_val INT64, float_val DOUBLE>>>>>

Why is this array type not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your code, the events field from the sessions table is already an array type, so it cannot be used in the last array_agg.

From the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg)

```
Supported Argument Types
All data types except ARRAY.
```